# Prove that the determinant of this matrix can be represented as a polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(A_{ij})$ be a square matrix of order $n$. Verify that the determinant of the matrix

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11}+x & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}+x & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}+x \end{array} \right)$,

can be represented as the polynomial $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x+a_n$, where each coefficient $a_k$ is the sum of the minors of order $k$ of the matrix $A$.

I tried to use the definition of determinant by cofactor expansion but it's very long, I was wondering if there's a shorter way to show this.

Comment: Is the lower left entry supposed to have a $+x$?

Comment: no, sorry. I already changed it.

Comment: You define $A$ twice, inconsistently. The displayed matrix should be called $A+xI_n$.

Comment: And you need to qualify "minor" to become "principal minor" for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write each column$~j$ of $A+xI_n$ as a sum of the column$~j$ of$~A$ and $x$ times column $j$ of$~I_n$. Now apply multi-linearity of the determinant with respect to the columns for each of the columns, to obtain a sum of $2^n$ determinants (each column was a sum of $2$ terms, and doubled the number of terms obtained for the whole determinant). The sum can be indexed by the $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,\}$, namely the subset of the columns for which the term involving $x$ was chosen. One obtains
$$
  \det(A+xI_n) = \sum_{S\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,\}}x^{|S|}\det M(S,A)
$$
where $M(S,A)$ denotes the matrix obtained from$~A$ by replacing the columns whose index appears in$~S$ by the corresponding column of$~I_n$.

Now fixing $S$, the determinant of $M(S,A)$ can be successively developed by the columns selected by$~S$, those that are taken from$~I_n$, which development involves only a single nonzero term each time. What remains is the determinant of the matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the rows and the columns whose index lies in$~S$. This is a [*principal* minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29#Other_applications) of order $n-|S|$. Thus after collecting the terms with the same power of$~x$, the coefficient$~a_k$ of $x^{n-k}$ is the sum of all principal minors of order$~k$ of$~A$. With that correction, the statement given has been proved.

Comment: nice!!-----------

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that a determinant is computed as the sum and product of finitely many polynomial terms, which results in a polynomial. You can show that with an induction argument, although I don't really think that's necessary.

Comment: I think the induction is necessary if you want to argue that the degree of the polynomial is $n$.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. That the determinant is a polynomial is obvious - but it's not obvious that each $a_k$ is the sum of the degree $k$ minors.